# How to tell if a SQL index has Casade on Delete enabled?

Tags: sql, indexing, azure-sql-database, cascading-deletes

Is there a SQL query that can tell whether a given index/constraint for a table is set to cascade on delete?

FYI, the database I'm using is SQL Azure

Comment: If your database supports `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` it has a `DELETE_RULE` column

Comment: For SQL Azure look at `sys.foreign_keys`. It has a `delete_referential_action` column. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx. Not sure if it supports `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, although the server versions of SQL Server do.